# Where i am wrong? Count total words excluding header and footer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-processing

This is the file i am trying to read and count the total no of words in this file [test.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3YKAd4buQS4RlNSVXl2amFRdEU/view?usp=sharing)

I have written a code for it:

```
def create_wordlist(filename, is_Gutenberg=True):
    words = 0
    wordList = []
    data = False
    regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    file1 = open("temp",'w+')
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        if is_Gutenberg:
            for line in file:
                if line.startswith("*** START "):
                    data = True
                    continue
                if line.startswith("End of the Project Gutenberg EBook"):
                    #data = False
                    break
                if data:
                    line = line.strip().replace("-"," ")
                    line = line.replace("_"," ")
                    line = regex.sub("",line)
                    for word in line.split():
                        wordList.append(word.lower()) 
                    #print(wordList)
                    #words = words + len(wordList)

    return len(wordList)          
    #return wordList
create_wordlist('test.txt', True)
```

Here are few rules to be followed:
        1. Strip off whitespace, and punctuation
        2. Replace hyphens with spaces
        3.skip the file header and footer. Header ends with a line that starts with "*** START OF THIS" and footer starts with "End of the Project".

> My answer: 60513 but the actual answer is 60570. This answer came with the question itself. It may be correct or wrong. Where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Who told you the answer is `60570`? I've run a regex search over those lines and I only got 60522.

Comment: It was mentioned in the question itself. How come you are getting 9 words more than me.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure, really. I've tried multiple different regex and I get different results every time. Fun stuff :) This was my most recent attempt: `words = map(lambda x: re.findall(r"([A-z\'*]+)", x), lines)`, but I got 60510.. (then I used itertools to group them and count the words)

Comment: @CoryMadden appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give a number for the actual answer -- the answer you consider correct, that you want your code to output.

You did not tell us how you got that number.

It looks to me like the two numbers come from different definitions of "word".

For example, you have in your example text several numbers in the form:
140,000,000

Is that one word or three?

You are replacing hyphens with spaces, so a hyphenated word will be counted as two.  Other punctuation you are removing.  That would make the above number (and there are other, similar, examples in your text) into one word.  Is that what you intended?  Is that what was done to get your "correct" number?  I suspect this is all or part of your difference.

At a quick glance, I see three numbers in the form above (counted as either 3 or 9, difference 6)
I see 127 apostrophes (words like wife's, which could be counted as either one word or two) for a difference of 127.

Your difference is 57, so the answer is not quite so simple, but I still strongly suspect different definitions of what is a word, for specific corner cases.

By the way, I am not sure why you are collecting all the words into a huge list and then getting the length.  You could skip the append loop and just accumulate a sum of len(line.split()).  This would remove complexity, which lessens the possibility of bugs (and probably make the program faster, if that matters in this case)

Also, you have a line:

```
                if line.startswith("*** START " in"):
```

When I try that in my python interpreter, I get a syntax error.  Are you sure the code you posted here is what you are running?  I would have expected:

```
                if line.startswith("*** START "):
```

Comment: Yes the code is a running. I have edited the part (line.startswith) in the main question. In the question it stated that we need to strip off the whitespaces and punctuations. It doesnt specify anything particular about digits or apostrophe. That why i am not sure where i am wrong. I just wanted to see the word list that why i was appending all the word into a list.&#128580; please see the rules that i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: I read the list of rules in the question.  You still haven't told us where you get the "correct" number from.  Apparently the rules are open to some kind of difference in interpretation.  How did you get the "correct" number?

Comment: Also, in your rules, you say, "strip off whitespace, and punctuation".  I see you stripping off punctuation.  But you don't strip off whitespace -- if you did you would get number of words equal to number of lines :-).  So something is not completely clear in the problem definition.

Comment: The answer was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Where?  You say, "the actual answer".  That does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand something.  People are taking of their time (quite a bit of it) to try to help you.  When asked a simple question by two different people, your answer is "was mentioned in the question".  Clearly, if two different people have the same question, it is *not* clear from your original question.  If people make an effort to help you, why not make a small effort to answer their questions?

Comment: Sorry about that it was an assignment question, in which the answer was mentioned. I have also tried removing the whitespaces. Still not getting that answer which was already mentioned in the question. I am not sure is it the correct one or not. That why I intended to know where I was doing it worng?

Comment: Thanks.  I understand now that this is a homework problem and they tell you the expected result, and you have to make your code match that.  Correct?  Your code looks correct to me; I would still guess there is some subtle difference, which might be understood from the exact wording of the question, in the definition of a word, or of punctuation, or some such.  Hard to know, without actually seeing the exact question....

Answer (score 0):

Without an example text file that shows this behaviour it is difficult to guess what goes wrong. But there is one clue: your number is *less* than what you expect. That seems to imply that you somehow glue together separate words, and count them as a single word. And the obvious candidate for this behaviour is the statement `line = regex.sub("",line)`: this replaces any punctuation character with an empty string. So if the text contains `that's`, your program changes this to `thats`.

If that is not the cause, you really need to provide a small sample of text that shows the behaviour you get.

**Edit**: if your intention is to treat punctuation as word separators, you should replace the punctuation character with a space, so: `line = regex.sub(" ",line)`.

Comment: OP provided example text.

Comment: Yeah. But not a "small sample". If the OP wants help, the first step is to trim the text to a small part that shows this behaviour.

Comment: I think the sample he provided is perfect, as it's the actual data he's working with.

Comment: Well, you go ahead and figure it out from that text. I don't plan to browse to over 60000 words to see where this goes wrong

Comment: I will give it a try by modifying my regexp.

Comment: I did that change, it resulted in 60891 words